# Do noble gases remain in their atomic states rather than form molecular bonds such as other gases are known to exist?

Tags: physical-chemistry, inert-gases

Just had a passing thought that given the fact that [noble gases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_gas) are inert and do not interact with other gases due to the fact that the outer shell is full, it would be the case that in nature they would be independent atoms rather than molecules - which is how other cases - such as oxygen and nitrogen are known to exist in the atmosphere. Is the understanding correct?

Basically when we mention [oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen) and [nitrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen) we tend to represent it in its common molecular representation `O`<sub>`2`</sub> and `N`<sub>`2`</sub>. But for noble gases such as [helium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium) and [neon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon) we just say `He` and `Ne` because given the fact that they do not form bonds they would be atomic in nature and as such that would be the way to represent them.

Is the understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the noble gases stay in atoms instead of form molecules. From the Wikipedia article on [noble gases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_gas):

> The noble gases (historically also the inert gases; sometimes referred to as aerogens) make up a class of chemical elements with similar properties; under standard conditions, they are all odourless, colourless, **monatomic** gases with very low chemical reactivity.

Comment: Thanks. Was not very familiar with the term [monatomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monatomic_gas) and in any case missed it.

Answer (score 1):

*Science is full of exceptions.*

Noble gases stay inert for most of the time unless exposed to very low temperatures.An example is the Helium dimer or He_2 consisting of two helium atoms.Its need to be kept at very low temperatures so that there is least kinetic energy in the atoms. Since the bond is very weak that its bond distance is the largest of all diatomic molecule being 5,200pm.

For comparision, Hydrogen has a van der waal radius of 120pm

They are held together by van der Waals forces arising due to change in electron density (similar to the formation of delta charges in covalent molecules). But this is not necessary to know at the elementary level as it seems, so my answer would be

**Yes, noble gases prefer to stay monoatomic molecules at standard conditions**

[Helium dimers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_dimer)

Comment: Thanks. To pick an answer though, went with the general case.